# Login/Cookie Security

Tags: php

I'm trying to set cookies. The problem is if I change in browser the cookie username I can log as any user without the password.

login.php

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
  $username = $_POST ['username'];
  $password = $_POST ['password'];
  if (empty($username) === true || empty ($password) === true) {
    $errors [] = 'er1';
  } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors [] = 'er2';
  } else {
    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
      $errors [] = 'er3';
    } else {
      setcookie("username", $username,  time()+3600*24*30);
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
      header('Location: logged_in.php');
      exit();
    }
  }
}
if (empty($errors) === false) {
  echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

function user.php

```
function logged_in () {
  return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['username'])) ? true : false;
}
function login($username, $password) {
  user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
  $username = sanitize ($username);
  $password = md5($password);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
  return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

core init.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_set_cookie_params(3600*24*30, "/");
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
if (logged_in() === true) {
  $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'password', 'username', 'email', 'age', 'gender', 'country', 'city', 'image_id');
}
$errors = array();
?>
```

Can anyone help me to secure the cookie? If the user changes the cookie username in the browser, redirect him to index and logout?

Comment: Don't set any more cookies than what the session already does automatically. Just drop your own cookie and go with session data.

Comment: Don't put sensitive data in cookies unless you have a specific reason and a way to encrypt them securely. Sessions (that use cookies in their turn) are designed for storing sensitive data, cookies are definitely not.

Comment: well i need cookie just for video chat autologin authz i wish i can go just for sessions

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cookies, use `$_SESSION` for everything. Just store the username in the session array and check if it is set to see if the user is logged in.. The only reason to use cookies for this is if you want the session to persist across multiple browser sessions.

---

If you must use cookies instead of storing the username in a cookie, store a randomly generated unique session ID (i.e. a 20 character+ random string) and match it to session data in a database.

For example, you create a database table which contains a session id, username, user id, and what time the session expires, etc. Then you set that session id as a cookie and when the user visits a page on your site you compare that id in the cookie to your database to find out who that user is.

This is much more secure than storing the username because the likelyhood that someone will be able to guess a 20+ character random string in the time before the session expires is very unlikely.

On an unrelated note, please don't use `md5()` for passwords. That's not what it was designed for and can be broken with tables, etc fairly quickly. Look into something like the more secure algorythms supported by `crypt()` if possible.

Comment: thx for answer the reason why i need cookie username is just for my video chat auto login im using this code so.addVariable("uid", "<? if ($_COOKIE['username']) print $_COOKIE['username']; ?>"); to get the user from cookies and login to video chat i have option for session but its not working

Comment: //session/cookie base authorization (Auto login)
if ($_SESSION['user_id']!="")
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION["user_id"]."'";
}
// Non session/cookie based autologin authorization
else if ($uid!="")
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_GET['uid']."'";
}
else
{
  echo '<auth error="AUTH_ERROR" />';
  exit;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
function logged_in () {

    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['username'])) ? true : false;
}
```

No anybody appears to be logged in as soon as they set a cookie on their side.

You should at the very least use `&&` instead of `||` but there really is no need to rely on cookie data (== user provided data...) for your login, so you should just use:

```
function logged_in () {
  return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

Comment: that's my mistake it looks like it dosn't neeed

Answer (score -2):

I use a single cookie but do something like `userid:hash(username+password)`.

Then do your check for a cookie

If the cookie exists pull the user_id and make sure the hash matches the hashed record.

If not, delete the cookie, and block the id.

They can alter the id, but it won't do them good if they can't match the username/password hash.

They shouldn't be able to figure out the hash if you are salting it well and can not extract passwords/usernames using it.

Comment: well im not that good to do that can you can explain me a little bit more?